# Making a new list from an existing list

Tags: python, list

Basically just looking if there is an easy way to reverse the list.
People were getting to confused with my original question.

This was the list: `words = ['hey', 'hi', 'hello', 'hi']`
How to reverse it (to a new list) and only add to new list if it is not already in it.

Comment: Can you give a basic example of desired input and output?

Comment: I didn't get this part: `After it is put to the end I would also like to bring it to the front.`

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. Do you want to build a distinct list from an existing list? and then sort it ?

Comment: Thought this was a bit confusing haha ok I'll do a sample input/output. I will edit the question right now. @Omid

Comment: In your first post you stated: _..then I would like it to store 'hi' only if it is not already in the list._ This is not a simple list reversal. Your edit created a **different** question.

Comment: @user5061 changed it to make more sense again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet iterates through the list of words in reverse; and adds new unique entries to a new list.

```
words = ['hey', 'hi', 'hello', 'hi']
result = []
for word in reversed(words):
    if word not in result:
        result.append(word)
print(result)
```

Output

```
['hi', 'hello', 'hey']
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting the first list to a [set()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) ensures duplicates are removed. Then the set is converted to a reversely sorted list.

```
final_lst = sorted(set(words), reverse=True)
```